# Does the series $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{n!}{\sqrt{(2n)!}}$ converge/diverge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Does the series $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{n!}{\sqrt{(2n)!}}$ converge/diverge?

I used the ratio test but I'm not sure:

$\begin{align} \frac{\frac{(n+1)!}{\sqrt{(2n+2)!}}}{\frac{n!}{\sqrt{(2n)!}}}
&=\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{(2n+1)(2n+2)}}\\
&=\frac{n+1}{4(n+1)^2\sqrt{2n+1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2n+1}} \end{align}$

The limit of that is smaller than $1$ so the series does converge. Is it correct ?

Comment: There is an error in the second line of your calculation.  The limit you should get is $1/2$.  But yes, the conclusion is still correct.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I can't take them out of the root like so $\frac{n+1}{4(n+1)^2\sqrt{2n+1}}$ ? That's what I wasn't sure about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is in response to [your question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615141/does-the-series-displaystyle-sum-infty-n-1-fracn-sqrt2n-converge?noredirect=1#comment1295451_615141).  It's too long for a comment so I'm posting it as an answer.

No, you can't take them out of the root like that.  One way to handle the denominator is by writing it like

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{(2n+1)\cdot(2n+2)} &= \sqrt{(2n+1)\cdot 2\cdot (n+1)} \\
&= \sqrt{2n+1} \sqrt{2} \sqrt{n+1},
\end{align}
$$

so that

$$
\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{(2n+1)(2n+2)}} = \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{2n+1} \sqrt{n+1}}.
$$

Now

$$
\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n+1}} = \sqrt{n+1},
$$

so

$$
\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{2n+1} \sqrt{n+1}} = \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2n+1}}.
$$

To calculate the limit of this as $n \to \infty$, divide the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt{n}$ to get

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{n+1}}{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{2n+1}} &= \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2 + \frac{1}{n}}} \\
&\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} \frac{\sqrt{1+0}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2 + 0}} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Woah community wiki, thanks for clearing that out.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

$$\left( \frac{n!}{\sqrt{(2n)!}} \right)^2=\frac{n!^2}{(2n)!}=\frac{1}{2n \choose n}$$

And

$${2n \choose n} \underset{n\to\infty}{\sim} \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{n\pi}}$$

So by ratio test, your series is convergent.

Comment: What the ? Did you just approximately limit an ncr ?

Comment: If $u_n \sim v_n$, convergence of $\sum u_n$ is equivalent to convergence of $\sum v_n$. Here it's a bit easier with $v_n=\sqrt{n\pi}/4^n$, since it's almost trivial to prove $v_{n+1}/v_{n} \to 1/4$.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly 
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{(2n+1)(2n+2)}}\to \frac{1}{2}.
$$
where $a_n=\dfrac{n!}{\sqrt{(2n)!}}$, and using the ratio test we get that the series converges absolutely.

Comment: @AntonioVargas You are right! I corrected it!

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to approach this problem using Stirling approximation for (n!).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_approximation
I just give this solution ignoring if you are or not allowed to use it. If you apply the second simplest approximation by Stirling
$$n! = \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n  $$
it is easy, using the ratio test, that the limit is smaller than unity.
What is more interesting is that, using the previous formula, the summation (from $n=1$ to $\infty$) is then approximated by $$\pi^{1/4} \text{PolyLog}\left[-\frac14, \frac12\right] \approx 1.52783...$$ while the exact value (not using at all any approximation for $n!$) leads to $1.58955...$

Comment: If you don't use LaTeX in your answers there's a fair chance not many will take the time to try to decypher what's written there...

Comment: @DonAntonio.I know that and I am so sorry of it. I think I already explained my problem to you and its becoming worse everyday. Whan my wife is close to my desk, she is able to make a very few things for me. Fortunately, from time to time, some users nicely edit my answers. Again, I can only apologize. Cheers.

Comment: Oh, no need to apologize, @Claude. You owe me, or anyone else, no explanations at all. I don't remember what your problem is, and I was just pointing out about the ease to read stuff here.

Comment: @DonAntonio. I thought I told you that I am "almost" (> 95%) blind, so I do not see what I am typing and evrything beside pure ASCII is very difficult to me. Moreover, ages don't make things easier.